# Can I finally build a mosasaur submarine?!

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

So now that tek vacuum chambers and the other nice toy are out I was wondering. Will I be able to place these vacuum chambers on a mosasaur platform and be able to build a small submersible? I know I need a generator and a lot of element.

Comment: You can start a separate single player game, spawn in the Dino and equipment and resources and try it out. Save to always try first in a test world before wasting tons of resources.